# TrueCrypt 7.1a on 14.04 mount issue

Tags: 14.04, truecrypt

Try to mount a TrueCrypt file
Error:

> device-mapper: resume ioctl on truecrypt8 failed: Invalid argument
>   Command failed

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, set the check mark to enable "DO NOT USE KERNEL CRYPTOGRAPHIC SERVICES" in TrueCrypt

See also http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2137911

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error with TrueCrypt 7.1a. It's a hardware issue: your flash memory card or stick is broken, buy another one. I brought a new memory micro SD card and it resolved the issue. You don't have to disable kernel cryptographic services in TrueCrypt.

Check your dmesg for wrong checksums and block bitmaps for your device:

```
$ dmesg | tail 
[124441.434842] loop: module loaded
[124442.292232] EXT4-fs (loop1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[124707.769242] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[124707.837535] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[124915.735395] EXT4-fs (loop0): ext4_check_descriptors: Block bitmap for group 0 not in group (block 734501930)!
[124915.735398] EXT4-fs (loop0): group descriptors corrupted!
[125044.588160] EXT4-fs (loop0): ext4_check_descriptors: Block bitmap for group 0 not in group (block 2614069506)!
[125044.588165] EXT4-fs (loop0): group descriptors corrupted!
[125105.695135] EXT4-fs (loop0): ext4_check_descriptors: Checksum for group 17 failed (32876!=19679)
[125105.695138] EXT4-fs (loop0): group descriptors corrupted!

$ uname -mr
3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64
```